# getting data by comparing fields in 2 lists in SP2013 event receiver

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, query

I have document library with name **XYZ** and list with name **MAPPING** .

**MAPPING** list conatins 2 columns they are **Title** and **dstURL** with type Hyperlink.

The values of XYZ library **Title** filed matched with MAPPING list **Title** filed.

I'm working on to write  **event receiver** which will copy the value for dstURL from library.

Comment: When do you want to fire the event

Comment: once it has been saved...ItemUpdated

Comment: OK, Is there any specific requirement for that. You have two option to perform this task one is using OOTB (declarative workflow ) and second is Custom event reciver on item added event

Comment: I have to move files whenever the user changes the status of doc to "obsolete". the destination to where the file has to be moved varies with each document library. that mapping of current library and destination lib. is present in the 'mapping' list. So i need to get the destination url for the current library. I have been told to write a custom event reciever for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Creating Simple Event Receiver in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/)

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {

     using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite"))
             {
               using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                 {
                   SPList mappingList = web.Lists.TryGetList("MAPPING");
                    var StatusOfDoc= properties.ListItem["StatusOfDoc"]


                if(StatusOfDoc == "obsolete")
                        {
                            if (mappingList != null)
                            {
                                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                query.Query = @"
                                            <Where><Eq>
                                                        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                                                        <Value Type='Text'>" + properties.ListItem.Title+ @"</Value>
                                            </Eq></Where>";

                                SPListItemCollection items = mappingList.GetItems(query);
                             foreach(item in items)
                             {

                                 item["dstURL"] = properties.ListItem["dstURL"];
                                 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                    item.Update();
                              }

                            }
                    }   }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an Event Receiver on doc library XYZ at `ItemUpdated` as the following

```
 public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {

         using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite"))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {

                            SPList desList = web.Lists.TryGetList("MAPPING");


                                if (desList != null)
                                {
                                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                    query.Query = @"
                                                <Where><Eq>
                                                            <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                                                            <Value Type='Text'>" + properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString()+ @"</Value>
                                                </Eq></Where>";

                                    SPListItemCollection items = desList.GetItems(query);

                                    if (items.Count != 0)
                                    {
                                     // it's exsist get the URL
                                    string URL=items.Fields["dstURL"].ToString();
                                     // continue your code
                                    }


                                }
                        }
                    }
        }
```